# how do I write xargs equivalent on windows for .sh file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

[command I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAfuq.png)   I faced an error when running this on windows `xargs -I{} -n 1 curl -o`

I have tried using wsl2 but it keeps trying to access the local npm packages and and keeps failing.

[I keep geting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEoAL.png)

Comment: Please DO NOT post images of your code and output when it is only TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of Git for Windows installed, which has many Linux commands and you should be able to use xargs also

Comment: I did just now but still not working